# Does string = string.replace(" ","") not remove trailing spaces?

Tags: java, android

I encountered a bug in my project today where a trailing space in a String was not replaced with

```
string = string.replace(" ", "")
```

and I had to trim the String to get rid of it.

Spaces in the middle where replaced as intended. This leads me to believe, that

```
string.replace(" ", "")
```

does not work on trailing spaces. Is that correct, and if so how does that make sense? Also is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

```
// example for value would be "100,0€ "
value = value.replace(" ", "").replace(",", ".").replace("€", "");
Log.d(TAG, value);
// Logcat: "D/BudgetEditFragment: 100.0 "
mBudget.setAmount(new BigDecimal(value)); //Bug crash caused with space in value
```

also:

```
value.getBytes()
```

before replace contains bytes: {49, 48, 48, 44, 48, 32} for value "100,0 "
after replace contains bytes:  {49, 48, 48, 46, 48, 32} for value "100.0 "

Comment: No, `replace(String, String)` does a non-regex replace of first parameter to the second. So any bugs you encountered were not related to `replace`.

Comment: I suppose it was a different kind of whitespace, it could be anything in UTF-8 or maybe just a normal tab or newline.

Comment: or it might be the space came up from `other string` that you are **appending** `without relevant code` and `output` it cant be judged !

Comment: use String::getBytes() to print a hex dump of this string so you can identify the character code doing the problem.

Comment: @GauravMall will do a hex dump to check for special whitespace characters

Comment: @Jujinko when using `€` then java file needs to be saved as UTF8

Comment: Added some information to my answer, I tested for a lot of time to find it.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does:

```
    String withSpace = "this is a test ";
    System.out.print(withSpace.replace(" ", ""));
    System.out.println("|");
```

**Output:**

`thisisatest|`

or consider using a regex:

```
withSpace.replaceAll("\\s", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow-up to @ScaryWombat's answer, the edit that you posted, I tested the code:

```
String value = "35,00€ ";
value = value.replace(" ", "").replace(",", ".").replace("€", "");
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(value); 
System.out.println(bigDecimal);
```

**Output:**

```
35.00
```

Maybe the error isn't with defining a `BigDecimal`. Check your `mBudget` class and also do hex dump to check for special characters.

**Edit: Information Dump**

So, the euro sign(this thing: `€`), has a byte array output:

```
[-30, -126, -84]
```

While space(this thing ), has a byte array output:

```
[32]
```

When using the OP's function, this is the byte array output, before and after:

```
Before: [49, 48, 48, 44, 48, 48, -30, -126, -84, 32]
After:  [49, 48, 48, 46, 48, 48]
```

Evidently, `44` has changed to `46` as `,`(comma) changed to `.`(period). Also, `-30`, `-126`, `-84` all three of whom are from the euro sign have been removed as a result of the `replace() function`. Also, `32` has been removed as space has been removed.

What is evident from the OP's edit, however, is that the `replace()` function has not removed the `32`(space). Here is the OP's test:

```
After: [49, 48, 48, 46, 48, 32]
```

**My reasoning:** The only reason I could find is that the `replace()` function is different in your case as you are using Android. If you haven't defined anything specifically, you are using Java 7 in Android. I tested it on Android but I was using Java 8. The same was true for me in my raw Java test. So, maybe that is a discrepancy between Java 7 and Java 8.

Comment: Yep, no problem with `String withSpace = "this is a test€ ";
  System.out.print(withSpace.replace(" ", "").replace("€", ""));
  System.out.println("|");` either

Comment: Yes. So the only error that could be is in the mBudget class, or because of some special character.

Comment: The exception for the crash was: ' java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1000 " ' at the BigDecimal

Comment: Did you log the `value` and there was still space? Also, did you do a hex dump?

Comment: Weird. I tested with the same exact code and it is showing without spaces.

Comment: I even tested this on Android, and it works. Btw, this is just interesting! Let's solve this.

Answer (score -2):

You can replace tailing space this:

```
string.trim();
```

Comment: if you read my question, that is what I ended up doing, but I was wondering why I had to do that